# Get MAX values in an array of objects and total

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have a method that accepts an array of objects and the number of array items is non-specific. The object properties are **Name** and **Value**. There are duplicate **Names** but paired with distinct **Value** like this:

```
{"Name_1", 100}
{"Name_1", 180}
{"Name_1", 500}
{"Name_2", 40}
{"Name_2", 150}
```

I would like to get the max **Value** for each **Name** which are:

```
{"Name_1", 500}
{"Name_2", 150}
```

and return total **Value** which is 650

Comment: You want to use `GroupBy` then `MaxBy`. `MaxBy` is part of MoreLINQ - https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
    Hello you can try this, 
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ClassTemp> tempList = new List<ClassTemp>();
        tempList.Add(new ClassTemp() {Name= "Name_1", Value = 100});
        tempList.Add(new ClassTemp() { Name = "Name_1", Value = 180});
        tempList.Add(new ClassTemp() { Name = "Name_1", Value = 500});
        tempList.Add(new ClassTemp() { Name = "Name_2", Value = 40});
        tempList.Add(new ClassTemp() { Name = "Name_2", Value = 150});

        var GroupList = tempList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(grp => new { Name = grp.Key, MaxValue = grp.Max(x => x.Value) }).ToList();

        int totalValue = GroupList.Sum(x => x.MaxValue);

    }

    public class ClassTemp

    {
        public string Name;
        public int Value;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a description on how you solve it and make sure you're code snippet only contains necessary code (and no free text :-)) needed to understand your answer (the code snippet as such doesn't need to be compiled, so things like adding an extra class can be omitted)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this:

Class:

```
public class Class
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
}
```

Then group them together like so:

```
        List<Class> ListOfClass = new List<Class>();   

        var Grouping = ListOfClass.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(group => new {
            Name = group.Key,
            Value = group.Max(x => x.Value)
        }).ToList();
```